# qt6 use opencv got error : LNK1104: cannot open file "opencv_world480d.lib"

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, cmake, lib, qt6

I installed OpenCV by using the pre-built libraries, more specifically, I downloaded `opencv-4.8.0-windows.exe` and ran it. It extracted an OpenCV folder under my *E* drive.

I have followed this tutorial and configured the environment variables:

- Created a Qt Widgets project
- Selected Qt's default build system (CMake)
- Selected "*Desktop QT 6.5.1 MSVC2019 64 bit*" in the kit selection.
- Copied the [OpenCV installation check code](https://opencv.org/get-started/) into `main.cpp`.
- Added `E:/opencv/build/include` into `include_directories`
- Added `opencv_world480d.lib` into `target_link_libraries`.

However, when I build the project, I get this error:

> LNK1104: cannot open file "opencv_world480d.lib"

Environment variable:

```
PATH=...;E:\opencv\build\x64\vc16\bin;  
OpenCV_DIR=E:\opencv\build\x64\vc16
```

`main.cpp` is copied from the OpenCV "*Get started*" page:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    std::string image_path = "001.jpg";
    Mat img = imread(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);

    imshow("Display window", img);
    int k = waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(opencv_checker VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# set(OpenCV_DIR E:/opencv/build) # i have also tried this one
set(OpenCV_DIR E:/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib)
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(E:/opencv/build/include)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(opencv_checker
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET opencv_checker APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(opencv_checker SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(opencv_checker
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(opencv_checker PUBLIC opencv_world480d.lib PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

set_target_properties(opencv_checker PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

install(TARGETS opencv_checker
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(opencv_checker)
endif()
```